# Create custom linq methods to create sql expressions

Tags: vb.net, linq, fluent-migrator

I'm trying to create custom linq methods (and classes) similar to the one's that can be found in FluentMigrator. I want to execute calls like this one:

```
Create.Table("Users")
    .WithColumn("UserId").AsInt32().Identity().PrimaryKey()
    .WithColumn("GroupId").AsInt32().NotNullable()
    .WithColumn("UserName").AsString(32).NotNullable()
    .WithColumn("Password").AsString(32).NotNullable();
```

I already implemented a class that handles `Create.Table` and `WithColumn`. Both methods return the same class type that represents the table to create.

What I don't understand is how to create the other mehtods (AsInt32, Identity, ...). Theses methods don't operate on my table class, but on a column class created by the `WithColumn` method.

How do I have to define my classes, so that chaining the table class to column class and vice versa works?

Here is the code I came up with so far:

```
Friend Class PdmCreateExpression
    Public Property Schema As String
    Public Property TableName As String
    Public Property Columns As List(Of PdmColumn)

    Public Sub New()
        Columns = New List(Of PdmColumn)
    End Sub

    Public Function Table(tableName As String) As PdmCreateExpression
        Me.TableName = tableName
        Return Me
    End Function

    Public Function WithColumn(columnName As String) As PdmCreateExpression
        Dim newColumn = New PdmColumn(columnName)
        Columns.Add(newColumn)
        Return Me
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Dim sqlString = "CREATE TABLE "

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Schema) Then sqlString += "[" + Schema + "]."
        sqlString += "[" + TableName + "] ("
        sqlString += String.Join(",", Columns.Select(Function(c) "[" + c.Name + "]"))
        sqlString += ")"

        Return sqlString
    End Function

End Class

Friend Class PdmColumn
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property SqlType As String

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub

    Public Function AsSqlType(sqlType As String)
        Me.SqlType = sqlType
        Return Me
    End Function
End Class

Friend MustInherit Class MigratorBase
    Protected Property _DbConnection As SqlConnection
    Protected Property Expressions As List(Of PdmCreateExpression)

    Sub New(dbConnection As SqlConnection)
        _DbConnection = dbConnection
        Expressions = New List(Of PdmCreateExpression)()
    End Sub

    Public MustOverride Sub Install()

    Public Function Create() As PdmCreateExpression
        Dim newExpression = New PdmCreateExpression()
        Expressions.Add(newExpression)
        Return newExpression
    End Function
End Class
```

Using the above code I can create my query like this:

```
Dim migrator = New MigratorBase(_DbConnection)
Dim sql = migrator.Create.Table("VersionInfo") _
                .WithColumn("Version") _
                .WithColumn("TimestampCreated") _
                .ToString()
```

Comment: Can you show some of your current code?

Comment: I added the implementation I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

These are not LINQ methods; they are called [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

What you're after can be done with so-called "marker interfaces":

```
interface ITableConvertibleExtensionTarget
{    
}

interface ITableExtensionTarget : ITableConvertibleExtensionTarget
{
}

interface IColumnExtensionTarget
{
}

class TableMap : ITableExtensionTarget
{    
}

class ColumnMap : IColumnExtensionTarget, ITableConvertibleExtensionTarget
{    
}

static class ColumnMapExtensions
{
    public static ColumnMap AsInt32(this IColumnExtensionTarget column)
    {
        // Mapping voodoo
        return column;
    }

    public static ColumnMap NotNullable(this IColumnExtensionTarget column)
    {
        // More voodoo
        return column;
    }
}

public static TableConvertibleExtensionTargetExtensions
{
    public static TableMap WithColumn(this ITableConvertibleExtensionTarget table)
    {
        return new TableMap(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton Gogolev. I copied your code to clean C# project and got it to compile. I probably missed something, because it doesn't work: I can do call like (new TableMap()).WithColumn().WithColumn(), but I can not insert e.g. .AsInt32() after a WithColumn call. Neither does it compile nor does IntelliSense recognize AsInt32. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I did my best to make the above code work, but I failed. Could somebody verfiy, that I didn't break the code? The above didn't compile. I had to apply casts in AsIn32 and NotNullable like this: "return (ColumnMap) colmn". Also I had to change the "public static TableConvertibleExtensionTargetExtensions" to "static class TableConvertibleExtensionTargetExtensions". But that can't be the reason why it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.